# android checkable listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am quite new in developing android applications.
I have created my own list adapter as show below and I want that list to be checkable.  What do I have to do so that my list contains a checkbox for each row?

```
public class listAvtivity extends ListActivity {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Vector<RowData> data;
RowData rd;
static final String[] title = new String[] {
        "*New*Apple iPad Wi-Fi (16GB)", "7 Touch Tablet -2GB Google Android",
"Apple iPad Wi-Fi (16GB) Rarely Used ","Apple iPad Wi-Fi (16GB) AppleCase"      };
static final String[] detail = new String[] {
        "1h 37m Shipping: $10.00","1h 39m Shipping: Free","58m 6s Shipping:$10.00","59m 30s Shipping: $10.95"   };
//private Integer[] imgid = {
 // R.drawable.bsfimg,R.drawable.bsfimg4,R.drawable.bsfimg2,
 // R.drawable.bsfimg5
//};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
data = new Vector<RowData>();
for(int i=0;i<title.length;i++){
try {
    rd = new RowData(i,title[i],detail[i]);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
   data.add(rd);
}
   CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list,
                                     R.id.title, data);
   setListAdapter(adapter);
   getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}
   public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,
                                                                long id) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected "
                    +(position+1)+"th item",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
       private class RowData {
       protected int mId;
       protected String mTitle;
       protected String mDetail;
       RowData(int id,String title,String detail){
       mId=id;
       mTitle = title;
       mDetail=detail;
    }
       @Override
       public String toString() {
               return mId+" "+mTitle+" "+mDetail;
       }
}
  private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {
  public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                        int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) {
 super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
}
      @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       ViewHolder holder = null;
       TextView title = null;
       TextView detail = null;
       //ImageView i11=null;
       RowData rowData= getItem(position);
       if(null == convertView){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
 }
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
             title = holder.gettitle();
             itle.setText(rowData.mTitle);
             detail = holder.getdetail();
             detail.setText(rowData.mDetail);
             //i11=holder.getImage();
             //i11.setImageResource(imgid[rowData.mId]);
             return convertView;
}
            private class ViewHolder {
            private View mRow;
            private TextView title = null;
            private TextView detail = null;
            //private ImageView i11=null;
            public ViewHolder(View row) {
            mRow = row;
 }
         public TextView gettitle() {
             if(null == title){
                 title = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.title);
                }
            return title;
         }
         public TextView getdetail() {
             if(null == detail){
                  detail = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.detail);
                    }
           return detail;
         }
        //public ImageView getImage() {
          //   if(null == i11){
            //      i11 = (ImageView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.img);
              //                        }
                //return i11;
        //}
     }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I liked Carlos Sessa solution from his book "50 Android hacks".

my activity_favorites.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/favContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My FavoritesActivity.java looks like this:

```
package com.myproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.myproject.R;
import com.myproject.model.Package;
import com.myproject.adapter.FavoritesPackageArrayAdapter;
import com.myproject.utils.DatabaseHelper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class FavoritesActivity extends Activity
{
    protected ListView list;
    protected String selectedPackage;
    protected ArrayList<Package> packages;
    protected FavoritesPackageArrayAdapter adapter;

    private DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorites);

        packages = db.getPackages();
        adapter = new FavoritesPackageArrayAdapter(this, -1, packages);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.favContainer);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onSelect(View view)
    {
        int pos = list.getCheckedItemPosition();
        if(ListView.INVALID_POSITION != pos)
            selectedPackage = packages.get(pos).getId();
    }

}
```

My ListView adapter (FavoritesPackageArrayAdapter.java) is quite simple:

```
package com.myproject.adapter;

import java.util.List;

import com.myproject.model.Package;
import com.myproject.view.PackageView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class FavoritesPackageArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Package>
{

    public FavoritesPackageArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Package> objects)
    {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if(convertView == null)
            convertView = new PackageView(getContext());

        Package pack = getItem(position);
        PackageView packView = (PackageView) convertView;
        packView.setPackage(pack);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

In order to have list items checkable, your view has to implement Checkable interface.
My PackageView.java looks like:

```
package com.myproject.view;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.myproject.R;
import com.myproject.model.Package;
import com.myproject.model.PackageEvent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class PackageView extends LinearLayout implements Checkable
{
    private View v;
    private TextView tv0;
    private TextView tv1;
    private TextView tv2;
    private TextView tv3;

    private CheckBox testCheckBox;

    public PackageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorites_package, this, true);
        tv0 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.favPackageId);
        tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.favEventDate);
        tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.favEventAddres);
        tv3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.favEventState);

        // I don't have checkbox in my layout, but if I had:
        // testCheckBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxId);
    }

    public void setPackage(Package pack)
    {
        // my custom method where I set package id, date, and time 
        ...
    }

    private Boolean checked = false;

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked()
    {
        return checked;
        // if I had checkbox in my layout I could
        // return testCheckBox.checked();
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked)
    {
        this.checked = checked;

        // since I choose not to have check box in my layout, I change background color
        // according to checked state
        if(isChecked())
            ...
        else
            ...
        // if I had checkbox in my layout I could
        // testCheckBox.setChecked(checked);
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle()
    {
        checked = !checked;
        // if I had checkbox in my layout I could
        // return testCheckBox.toggle();
    }

}
```

And finally xml layout of each list item (favorites_package.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/favPackageId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/favTimeDateContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/favEventDate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/favEventAddres"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
    </LinearLayout>


   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/favEventState"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you wanted to have actual checkbox in your layout it's xml should look something like:

```
<CheckBox
       android:id="@+id/checkBoxId"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:clickable="false"
       android:focusable="false"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

If you left checkbox clickable, you could only check it only by clicking on checkbox itself.
Also don't make your layout clickable, for some reason it doesn't work with Checkable interface.

Comment: How does the onSelect(...) method work across those classes?

Answer (score 0):

Look at that code sample

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-multiple-choice-example

--- Edit --

You did not post your xml files. To have a custom list row I did it this way. First I setcontentview which contains my listview in your java code.

```
setContentView(R.layout.list_main);
```

Then your list_main.xml file should contain a listview

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

AFterwards set data adapter

```
  setListAdapter(new YOUR_ADAPTER_CLASS(this, R.layout.list_item, YOUR_OBJECT));
```

To get a custom list item, create a list_item.xml file which contains your custom row. You can put linearlayouts, images or checkboxes here.

Then get your listview

```
  ListView listView = getListView();
```

You can set onitemclick listener here

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
             //YOUR_CODE_HERE
        }
      });
```

Then in your custom adapter file you can implement getview function

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }
            //YOU CAN GET EVERY OBJECT AND SET YOUR CUSTOM ROW like below
            //view.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_OBJECT_ID_HERE);
            return view;
    }
```

I could not look at your code and say what is wrong, but this is the correct way of implementing custom rows for listview in android.

Comment: this is a general example. could you help me what i have to change in my code

Comment: you should not send code and ask for what is wrong. as I do not have project, did not look at where it did not work and you did not put logcat content if there exists an error. In general just put the code that does not work and write logcat error content. :) lets back to code. get your listview from your xml. and call your_list_View_object_here.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

Comment: I did what you told me, but still the checkbox does not appear on the list item