# Sum up a group of dynamic objects

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm currently a bit overstrained how to realize the following problem.
I want to realize a product overview as the figure shows.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/e6BlL9T.jpg]

In C# I would add a panel and add objects of one product (checkbox, textview, imageview) with a fixed position specification. And just group it for the others.
But how can I realize this (optimal) under Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) with [custom row layouts](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_example).

Your custom row layout can be a RelativeLayout, containing a CheckBox, some TextViews and an ImageView. It will be reused for every row by the ListView adapter. If you need the checkbox to indicate which rows the user selected (common in Windows UIs), consider implementing [Checkable list views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939392/android-checkable-listview).

Comment: Should i create this all programmatically or with an xml layout?

Comment: I'd recommend using an XML layout, as you can see more easily what you're doing.

Comment: As I said, i dont know the amount of products. Which parts would you outsource in a xml file?

Comment: The layout for each row - this should be in a separate XML file, not the one from the activity. There are countless tutorials on the Internet on how to implement this.