# How to Set ID's on programmatically created checkboxes?

Tags: android, checkbox, view, simplecursoradapter

I am working on a small app that helps me to track my nutrition.Now, i build a Layout with an Adapter.For this purpose i'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter because all needed data comes from my database.Everything went fine except one thing:

All checkboxes has the same id. So I'm not able to check each of them. There is one solution i know how it can be solved but in this case i cant use an xml file to generate ids because i don't know how many checkboxes will be next time i run the app.

Here is my code:

```
public void getIdAndDate()
{
    db = new DATABASE(this);

    SQLiteDatabase sqldb = db.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] Columns = {"_id", "date"};
    int[] toViews = {R.id.entry_id, R.id.entry_date};

    Cursor cursor1;

    cursor1 = sqldb.query(db.TABLE_DAILY_CONSUMPTION, Columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    numRows = cursor1.getCount();

    int id[] = new int[numRows];
    String date[] = new String[numRows];

    for(int i = 0; i<numRows; i++)
    {
        cursor1.moveToNext();
        id[i] = cursor1.getInt(0);
        date[i] = cursor1.getString(1);
    }

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.layout_entry, cursor1, Columns, toViews, 0);
    entries.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And this is my Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/entry_id"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/entry_date"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/entry_selection"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />
```

I really try to figure out how i can solve the problem but i cant even imagine which possibilities i have.

Comment: You can simply call `setId` to your `CheckBox` view with any integer value of choice. Are you doing that only now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939392/android-checkable-listview and other resources are available from a Google search on `android listview checkable` or `android listview checkbox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I'm not using checkboxes anymore. Instead i'm using the entries i already have and work with the setOnItemClickListener and create a new function to deal with the selections. The new code:

```
public void getIdAndDate()
{
    db = new DATABASE(this);

    SQLiteDatabase sqldb = db.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] Columns = {"_id", "date"};
    int[] toViews = {R.id.entry_id, R.id.entry_date};

    Cursor cursor1;

    cursor1 = sqldb.query(db.TABLE_DAILY_CONSUMPTION, Columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    numRows = cursor1.getCount();

    int id[] = new int[numRows];
    String date[] = new String[numRows];

    for(int i = 0; i<numRows; i++)
    {
        cursor1.moveToNext();
        id[i] = cursor1.getInt(0);
        date[i] = cursor1.getString(1);
    }

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.layout_entry, cursor1, Columns, toViews, 0);
    entries.setAdapter(adapter);
    entries.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler);
}

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        selections(v, (int)id);
    }
};

public void selections(View view, int id)
{
    if(Counter < 7)
    {
        if(selections[0] == id || selections[1] == id || selections[2] == id || selections[3] == id || selections[4] == id || selections[5] == id || selections[6] == id)
        {
            MESSAGE.message(db.context, "Diese Auswahl hast du bereits getroffen!");
        }
        else
        {
            selections[Counter] = id;
            view.setBackgroundColor(0xAACCCCCC);
            Counter++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MESSAGE.message(db.context, "Du hast die maximal mögliche Anzahl an Auswahl getroffen!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to set `Id` dynamically to any view, first define an id in your resource file:

```
<resources>
    <item name="custom_id" type="id" />
</resources>
```

Then in your code:

```
view.setId(R.id.custom_id);
```

Comment: In some cases this solution works but in this situation i cant use an xml file to generate ids because i don't know how many checkboxes will be next time i run the app.